# How can i broadcast a 2x2 matrix of an image into another matrix to obtain the results below

Tags: python

I have an image of size 3x4 - `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]`.
I want to broadcast a 2x2 matrix of the image to another matrix of the same size but zeros values
`[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`, such that the final result is..

```
[[1,2,0,0],[5,6,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

[[0,2,3,0],[0,6,7,0],[0,0,0,0]]

[[0,0,3,4],[0,0,7,8],[0,0,0,0]]

[[0,0,0,0],[5,6,0,0],[9,10,0,0]]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,6,7,0],[0,10,11,0]]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,7,8],[0,0,11,12]]
```

Comment: You mean somehting like numpy's way of doing this ? [Numpy's way](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html#numpy.broadcast)

Comment: There's already something called "broadcasting" in NumPy and other array math libraries/languages. This isn't it.